# Binding kendo grid to datatable retrevied from database

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

We can retrieve data from database in form of data tables or datasets and we can bind the same to grid view or drop download list, etc.

```
grivew1.datasource=dtUsers;
```

Is there any way possible to bind the data to a kendo grid without using MVC.
If possible please share some sample code.

Comment: What do you mean "bind the data to a kendo grid without using MVC"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo UI grid suppports data binding and you can command the widget to display data either from local or remote data storage. For local data binding you simply need to supply an array of JavaScript objects/JSON via the dataSource data property of the grid, or utilize the Kendo UI DataSource as a mediator between the grid and the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways you can do that, the main thing is to set the datasource of the data grid.

See the link below, Telerik has several examples available on their website.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/overview

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/data-binding

Answer (score -1):

Just create a datasource and assign the JS array to it:

```
var sampleArray[]; //get data in this array

var sampleDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        data: sampleArray,
        model: {
            fields: {
                ID: { type: "number" },
                Label: { type: "string" },
                Description: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
});
```

then bind the datasource to the grid:

```
sampleGrid.data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(sampleDataSource );
```